# sql pivot two columns to same column values

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to transform data, and have somewhat succesfully done it so far but have now hit a dead-end and looking for some help on my issue.

I have four columns in my data. Cat1 (old category), val1 (old value), cat2(new or current category) and val2 (its current value.

What I want is for each combination of cat 1 and cat 2 the val2, negative for the old category in its respective column, and positive for the new category.

example data:

```
 cat1   cat2   val1   val2
 A      B      10     30
 A      A      5      20
 C      A      33     15
 B      C      23     20
 B      A      14     5
 C      B      18     20
 A      B      14     0
```

The outcome I'm looking for is:

```
change     A     B    C
AtoB      -30   +30   
AtoC       0          0
BtoA      -5     +5
BtoC             -20  +20
CtoA      +15        -15
CtoB            +20  -20
```

I've succesfully by using pivot&unpivot with the help of the CASE clause created a table that takes into consideration only one of the columns. So I only get one value per row:

```
select * from (select
cat1
SUM(
    CASE WHEN cat1 = A AND cat2 = B THEN val2*-1 ELSE 0 END 
  ) AtoB,
SUM(
    CASE WHEN cat1 = A AND cat2 = C THEN val2*-1 ELSE 0 END 
  ) AtoC,
SUM(
    CASE WHEN cat1 = B AND cat2 = C THEN val2*-1 ELSE 0 END 
  ) BtoC,
SUM(
    CASE WHEN cat1 = C AND cat2 = B THEN val2*-1 ELSE 0 END 
  ) CtoB,
SUM(
    CASE WHEN cat1 = C AND cat2 = A THEN val2*-1 ELSE 0 END 
  ) CtoA,
SUM(
    CASE WHEN cat1 = B AND cat2 = A THEN val2*-1 ELSE 0 END 
  ) BtoA
 FROM table
  group by cat1,cat2)
  unpivot (
  value for cat in 
 (AtoB,AtoC,BtoC,CtoB,CtoA,BtoA)) up
pivot (
sum(value) for cat1 in ('A','B','C')
```

the problem here is that I only get the value on cat1, and not on cat2, despite them sharing the values. One solution I can think of is to create some complicated join, or to save this table and then do a new CASE clause on each row to duplicate the value times -1, but feel like both of those solutions are not very good, and that there is some better solution which I am missing.

After the unpivot clause I end up with:

```
cat1     cat   value
A        AtoB   -30
A        AtoC    0
B        Bto    0
B        AtoB   0
...      ...    ...
```

which the PIVOT statement transforms to

```
cat        A     B    C
AtoB      -30      
AtoC                 
BtoA              -5    
BtoC             -23
CtoA                 -15
CtoB                 -20
```

Comment: I don't follow the logic that transforms the sample data into the desired results.  Can you try to explain it?

Comment: I expended a bit on the question

Comment: To clarify: AtoB means change of cat1 =A and cat2=B, then ? I dont understand the operation. Please exaplain.

Comment: You are correct. AtoB means it went from Cat1 = A to cat2=B, and the value of this should be negative val2 in the column A (since A decreased) and positive in column B

Comment: It's very unclear how your expected results are generated; please explain the actual method you're using. For example, why does `BtoC` use the `val1` value, when it looks like everything else is using `val2`?

Comment: Sorry about that, ive expanded on my question. The case you mentioned was a mistake on my part. Val1 is actually irrelevant atm and only val2 is used.